# Javascript - sharing a method between objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two Javascript functions "HighlightA()", and "HighlightB()" which are both used to highlight a different label on the page. I want to associate whichever one of these functions I choose to each object in my array of objects..

```js
var A = function HighlightA() {
  Label_Box_1.style.color = "green";
  Label_Box_1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
};

var B = function HighlightB() {
  Label_Box_2.style.color = "green";
  Label_Box_2.style.fontWeight = "bold";
};

var MyArrayOfObjects = [
  { HighlightText: A, KEY2: myvalue2 },
  { HighlightText: B, KEY2: myvalue2 }
];

MyArrayOfObjects[0]["HighlightText"]; //function doesn't get executed.

MyArrayOfObjects[0].HighlightText(); //function still doesn't get executed.
```

Can anyone tell me how I should be doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var A = function HighlightA() {
    console.log('Called A');
  }
  var B = function HighlightB() {
    console.log('Called B')
  }
  var MyArrayOfObjects = [
    { HighlightText: A, KEY2: "myvalue2", },
    { HighlightText: B, KEY2: "myvalue2" },
  ];
  MyArrayOfObjects[0]["HighlightText"]();  //function doesn't get executed.
  MyArrayOfObjects[1].HighlightText();
```

Comment: How is this different than `MyArrayOfObjects[0].HighlightText()`, which, according to OP doesn't get executed.

Comment: If this works, OP's  code with `MyArrayOfObjects[0].HighlightText()` also should work. The question should be closed as no [mcve]

Comment: @adiga Yes I am agree with you, but it may be possible that because of some reason it may not be working at OP's end. So added a working solution, so it may help him.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code has errors.

```
var A = function HighlightA() {
  console.log('hi');
};

var B = function HighlightB() {
  console.log('hi');
};

var MyArrayOfObjects = [
  { HighlightText: A, KEY2: '1' },
  { HighlightText: B, KEY2: '1' }
];

MyArrayOfObjects[0].HighlightText();
```

This works just fine for me on a node and a browser environment.Your issue lies elsewhere, not with how you're accessing and executing the function.